# Can I set a <div> with an ID that has been dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my program I am dynamically creating feedback boxes to respond to user input. My problem is, I don't know how many of these pieces of feedback will be outputted. I have created a function in my javascript that assigns an id to each new element I create at runtime by concatenating a string with a variable number - which is incremented after every time the constructor is called - and appending it to my CSS class for styling, however I'm not sure how to reference a varying  id in my html so that they actually appear on the screen.

```
var counter = 0;

function constructFeedbackBox() {
    counter++;
    var newElement = 'toast' + counter;
    var i = null;
    i = document.createElement('div');
    i.id = newElement;
    i.className = ".toastStyle";
}
```

In addition, if there are any problems with the way I've done my javascript to create my Id and/or append it to my class, the info would be much appreciated (I'm still pretty new to this)

Comment: well depending on what you're doing, why do you need to refer to the item by ID?

Comment: Why create the element and then get the element? [`document.createElement()` returns the created element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), so just do `var i = document.createElement('div'); i.id = newElement;`. Also note that `className` should be set to the name of the class, with no `.`. So, `i.className = "toastStyle";`

Comment: thanks, will make this change, I guess I was just making sure I didn't leave anything out when attempting to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `document.createElement()` takes a tagName as an input. If you are making divs, your line should read `document.createElement('div');`.

You can then do `i.setAttribute(id, 'toast' + counter);`.

What are you trying to accomplish overall with this? Maybe there is a better approach. Also worth noting that IDs must be unique, so be careful about that.

Comment: I left out most of my function, which includes 2 parameters, but basically as this goes on it assigns a message, title, and icon to the toast based on what's passed to it. It also calls a function within itself that moves all existing toasts down the height of the new toast. I have tested it with hard coded Id's and know this all works correctly, so I have left it out. Basically I just need a way to reference each element as they are created in order to output them on my webpage (I'm currently using a button for testing purposes that creates a new toast every time it's clicked)